# How to achieve privacy for value saved in `this` in constructor function?

Tags: javascript

What options do I have to achieve privacy on values I need to save in `this` in a constructor function? For example, a simple `Stack` implementation:

```js
function Stack(){
  this._stack = {}
  this._counter = 0
}

Stack.prototype.push = function (item){
  this._stack[this._counter++] = item
  return this
}

Stack.prototype.pop = function (){
  Reflect.deleteProperty(this._stack, --this._counter);
  return this
}

Stack.prototype.peek = function (){
  return this._stack[this._counter - 1]
}

Stack.prototype.length = function (){
  return Object.values(this._stack).length
}
```

If these methods are not defined as prototype methods, I can easily private them like this:

```js
function Stack(){
  let _stack = {}
  let _counter = 0

  this.push = function (item){
    _stack[_counter++] = item
    return this
  }

  this.pop = function (){
    Reflect.deleteProperty(_stack, --_counter);
    return this
  }

  this.peek = function (){
    return _stack[_counter - 1]
  }

  this.length = function (){
    return Object.values(_stack).length
  }
}
```

This way `_stack` and `_counter` are not exposed, but then these methods are not on prototype chain.

Is it possible to achieve privacy, while the protected values are saved in `this`?

Comment: Use private fields. For example:  `#_stack = {}`

Comment: Only private fields which probably is fine depending on the browser support you are targeting.

Comment: https://curiosity-driven.org/private-properties-in-javascript#symbols

Comment: Coming from a strong OO background, when I started to learn js, I tried my best to apply OO concepts like private fields to it and to create a "decent" way to use OO in js. With time and learning some fws and their ways, I understood that OO isn't the final answer to everything, there can be other ways to organize your code and simply things don't work that way in some languages. I advise you to learn rxjs and read the excelent "Composing Software" by Eric Elliot about funcional programming in js. OO is in a downward trend.

Comment: @NelsonTeixeira OO will stay relevant for a long time to come. Both OO and functional programming have their own advantages (and disadvantages) and fulfil different roles. I do agree that you generally speaking don't want to force the concept of one languages down another ones throat. JavaScript is not Java nor C#.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

MDN provides an example of private properties in their [Keyed collections guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Keyed_collections).

> #### [WeakMap object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Keyed_collections#weakmap_object)
>
> The [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) object is a collection of key/value pairs in which
> the **keys are objects only** and the values can be arbitrary values.
> The object references in the keys are held *weakly*, meaning that they
> are a target of garbage collection (GC) if there is no other reference
> to the object anymore. The `WeakMap` API is the same as the `Map` API.
>
> One difference to `Map` objects is that `WeakMap` keys are not
> enumerable (i.e., there is no method giving you a list of the keys).
> If they were, the list would depend on the state of garbage
> collection, introducing non-determinism.
>
> For more information and example code, see also "Why *Weak*Map?" on
> the [`WeakMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap) reference page.
>
> One use case of `WeakMap` objects is to store private data for an
> object, or to hide implementation details. The following example is
> from Nick Fitzgerald's blog post ["Hiding Implementation Details with
> ECMAScript 6 WeakMaps"](http://fitzgeraldnick.com/weblog/53/). The private data and methods belong inside
> the object and are stored in the *`privates`* `WeakMap` object.
> Everything exposed on the instance and prototype is public; everything
> else is inaccessible from the outside world because *`privates`* is
> not exported from the module.
>
> ```
> const privates = new WeakMap();
>
> function Public() {
>   const me = {
>     // Private data goes here
>   };
>   privates.set(this, me);
> }
>
> Public.prototype.method = function () {
>   const me = privates.get(this);
>   // Do stuff with private data in `me`...
> };
>
> module.exports = Public;
> ```

Applied to your scenario this could look like this:

```
const Stack = (function () {
  const privates = new WeakMap();

  function Stack() {
    privates.set(this, { stack: {}, counter: 0 });
  }

  Stack.prototype.push = function (item) {
    const _ = privates.get(this);
    _.stack[_.counter++] = item;
    return this;
  };

  Stack.prototype.pop = function () {
    const _ = privates.get(this);
    Reflect.deleteProperty(_.stack, --_.counter);
    return this;
  };

  Stack.prototype.peek = function () {
    const _ = privates.get(this);
    return _.stack[_.counter - 1];
  };

  Stack.prototype.length = function () {
    const _ = privates.get(this);
    return Object.values(_.stack).length;
  };
  
  return Stack;
})();
```

Comment: Marking this answer as correct, as this is simple, effective and avoided using class(which is what I want originally)

Comment: @JohnWinston do note that if someone hijacks `WeakMap` it won't actually be hidden.. and yes it can still be manipulated.. honestly, the functions inside the functions work better

Comment: @TheBombSquad I disagree. When using the nested functions you are still creating the methods for each `Stack` instantiated. At that point you might as well not use `prototype` methods, and instead use the solution given by OP in the second code block.

Comment: @3limin4t0r well post up a fiddle proving ur point ;-;

Answer (score 9):

Here is an example of using private fields. You can make them static with the `static` keyword, but that is not necessary in this example.

```js
class test {
    #lol = 29;
    #mas = 15;
    constructor() {
        this.#lol++;
        this.#mas--;
        return {
            value: this.#lol - this.#mas
        };
    }
};
console.log(new test().value); // --> 16
```

Comment: I think Private field proposal is still in stage 2?

Comment: It is in stage 3 as taken from [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Public_class_fields)

Comment: Note that at this point in time you'll need a transpiler (like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)) if you want to use this solution. Private class fields are not yet supported by all major browsers. You can check browser compatibility [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#browser_compatibility).

Answer (score 4):

**This answer does not create private properties.** However if the intent of the question is to prevent a user from accidentally accessing "private" properties or to prevent property conflict you can use [symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol).

A property conflict happens when your function expects property *A*, while a library (or any other code) also expects property *A* but for another purpose.

```
const Stack = (function () {
  const stack = Symbol("_stack");
  const counter = Symbol("_counter");

  function Stack() {
    this[stack] = {};
    this[counter] = 0;
  }

  Stack.prototype.push = function (item) {
    this[stack][this[counter]++] = item;
    return this;
  };

  Stack.prototype.pop = function () {
    Reflect.deleteProperty(this[stack], --this[counter]);
    return this;
  };

  Stack.prototype.peek = function () {
    return this[stack][this[counter] - 1];
  };

  Stack.prototype.length = function () {
    return Object.values(this[stack]).length;
  };
  
  return Stack;
})();
```

The above code does not prevent a user from accessing the properties, but makes it somewhat hard. You could still access them using the following code:

```
const stack = new Stack();
const [_stack, _counter] = Object.getOwnPropertySymbols(stack);
stack[_stack]   // gives access to the stack
stack[_counter] // gives access to the counter
```

Symbol properties are excluded from a lot of common functions like `Object.keys()`, `Object.values()`, `Object.entries()`, and also from `for...in` loops.

Answer (score 3):

I created a function that has access to private data and returns a function with a closure containing methods for working with them (keeps everything in one place) external functions serve only as a kind of pointers to the internal functions of `the provider`.

```
class Stack{
  constructor(){
    this.provider = this.provider('init', this)
  }  
  provider(type, args){
    const state = {} 
    if (type === 'init'){
      state._stack = [];
      state._counter = 0;
      state.this = args;
    } 
    return function (type, args) {
      switch(type){
        case 'push':
          return _push(args)
        case 'pop':
          return _pop()
        case 'peek':
          return _peek()
        case 'length':
          return _length()
      }
      function _push(item){
        state._stack.push(item)
        return state.this
      }
      function _pop(){
        const item = state._stack.pop()
        console.log(item)
        return state.this
      }
      function _peek(){
        return state._stack[state._stack.length-1]
      }
      function _length(){
        return Object.values(state._stack).length
      }
    }
  }
  push(item){
    return this.provider('push', item)
  }
  pop(){
    return this.provider('pop')
  }
  peek(){
    return this.provider('peek')
  }
  length(){
    return this.provider('length')
  }
}
```

**tests**:

```
s = new Stack();
g = new Stack();

s.push(1).push(2).push(3)
console.log('length s:', s.length()) // 3
s.pop(/* 3 */).pop(/* 2*/)
console.log(s.peek())
s.pop(/* 1 */)
console.log('length s:', s.length()) // 0

g.push('a').push('b').push('c').pop(/* c */).push('d')
g.pop(/* d */)                
console.log('g.peek()', g.peek(), /* b */)
g.pop(/* b */)                
g.pop(/* a */)                                              
console.log('length g:', g.length()) // 0
```